# Django query / Iteration issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a fairly noob question regarding iteration that I can't seem to get correct.

I have a table that houses a record for every monthly test a user completes, if they miss a month then there is no record in the table.

I want to pull the users history from the table then for each of the 12 months set a Y or N as to their completed status.

Here is my code:

```
    def getSafetyHistory(self, id):
    results = []
    safety_courses = UserMonthlySafetyCurriculums.objects.filter(users_id=id).order_by('month_assigned')
    for i in range(1, 13):
        for s in safety_courses:
            if s.month_assigned == i:
                results.append('Y')
            else:
                results.append('N')

    return results
```

So my ideal result would be a list with 12 entries, either Y or N
i.e results = [N,N,Y,N,N,Y,Y,Y,N,N,N,Y]

The query above returns 2 records for the user which is correct, but in my iteration I keep getting 24 entries, obviously due to the outter and inner loops, but I am not sure of the "pythonic" way I should be doing this without a ton of nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways to do this. Here is one idea.

It looks like you are only going to get records for courses that have been completed. So you could pre-build a list of 12 results, all set to no. Then after you query the database, you flip the ones to yes that correspond to the results you got.

```
results = ['N'] * 12  # prebuild results to all no

safety_courses = UserMonthlySafetyCurriculums.objects.filter(
                     users_id=id).order_by('month_assigned')

for course in safety_courses:
    results[course.month_assigned - 1] = 'Y'
```

This assumes `month_assigned` is an integer between 1 and 12, as your code hints at.

Comment: Yes that worked like a charm! Thanks for much for the help, definitely a snippet I will save.

Thanks again!